# The length limit of `match` using 'finditer'

Tags: python, regex

Suppose the a following string

```
s = '\nThe model layer\nDjango provides an abstraction layer (the “models”) for structuring and manipulating the data of your Web application. Learn more about it below:\n\nModels: Introduction to models | Field types | Indexes | Meta options | Model class\nQuerySets: Making queries | QuerySet method reference | Lookup expressions\nModel instances: Instance methods | Accessing related objects\nMigrations: Introduction to Migrations | Operations reference | SchemaEditor | Writing migrations\nAdvanced: Managers | Raw SQL | Transactions | Aggregation | Search | Custom fields | Multiple databases | Custom lookups | Query Expressions | Conditional Expressions | Database Functions\nOther: Supported databases | Legacy databases | Providing initial data | Optimize database access | PostgreSQL specific features\n'
```

Retrieve the titles by `findall`:

```
In [17]: chapter = re.findall(r'\n.+:', s)
In [18]: chapter
Out[18]:
['\nDjango provides an abstraction layer (the “models”) for structuring and manipulating the data of your Web application. Learn more about it below:',
 '\nModels:',
 '\nQuerySets:',
 '\nModel instances:',
 '\nMigrations:',
 '\nAdvanced:',
 '\nOther:']
```

It works well, but as for `finditer`

```
In [19]: chap = re.finiter(r'\n.+:', s)
In [21]: [ i for i in chap]
Out[21]:
[<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(16, 162), match='\nDjango provides an abstraction layer (the “mode>,
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(163, 171), match='\nModels:'>,
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(247, 258), match='\nQuerySets:'>,
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(322, 339), match='\nModel instances:'>,
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(384, 396), match='\nMigrations:'>,
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(482, 492), match='\nAdvanced:'>,
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(670, 677), match='\nOther:'>]
```

Compare their index[0]

```
'\nDjango provides an abstraction layer (the “models”) for structuring and manipulating 
the data of your Web application. Learn more about it below:',

[<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(16, 162), 
match='\nDjango provides an abstraction layer (the “mode>,
```

`finditer` failed to cut completed paragraph.

There's no limiting on match length refering to the official documentation.[6.2. re — Regular expression operations — Python 3.6.4rc1 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html)

What's the problem?

Comment: You're looking at the `repr()` of the returned `match` objects, which truncates the match. Retrieve it with e.g. `group(0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you notice, the first item spans indices 16 to 162, and has a length of 146 characters. `finditer` works but its representation (i.e. the output of its `__repr__()` method) is what is being shown here, as noted in the comments by [kindall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/416467/kindall).